# replacing '01-01-0001' with empty string on databound DevExpress.XtraEditors.TextEdit control

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

Our not to be changed datalayer returns the `DateTime.Mindate` when the record's column has a NULL value.
So when you put a `null` value in a record's column and you read it again, you get `01-01-0001`.

When binding this value to a `DevExpress.XtraEditors.TextEdit control` this value (01-01-0001) ofcourse is displayed in the control.

Now we want to show the control as being empty (no content), but i don't know how to achieve that.

I did find out that you can set a custom display text for the control when the object's attribute is NULL, but that doesn't work ofcourse because the value is `01-01-0001` and not null.

So in short: if it's a date with the value of `01-01-0001`, show nothing in the control, otherwise, show the date.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `DateEdit` control instead of a `TextEdit`

Set the `NullDate` property to `1-1-0001`

Turn off the drop down button in the "Buttons" settings if you do not require it. It will then look just like a `TextEdit`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the `FormatEditValue` event to format the date in the way you want.

In the other direction, you use the `ParseEditValue` event to parse user input.